# How to Update the value of point in Highchart?

Tags: json, highcharts

I have a Highchart that is receiving JSON data via AJAX and jQuery in setInterval function,when i use `series.data[i].y = response[i].y` , the value of y is change ,but dosent Display in chart and the hight of point has previous value but in tooltip show recent value ? and the x value dosent changhe at all, please help me how to update the the x and y value if it is changhed?

```
           chart:{ renderTo: 'container',
            zoomType: 'xy',
            plotBackgroundImage: 'graphics/skies.jpg',
            events: {
                load: function () {                    
          var series = this.series[0];setInterval(function () {ajax({type: "POST",url: "/Home/GetData",data: null),contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",success: function (response) {          for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {      if (series.data[i].y =response[i].y || series.data[i].category != response[i].x) {          series.data[i].y =response[i].y; series.data[i].category = response[i].x;} }}, dataType: "json",failure: ajaxCallFailed });}, 50000);}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not directly modify the this.series[0] object. Highcharts has api calls that you can use, which should be uses for correct results and not breaking anything unintentionally. 
Here is a list of methods supported by the series object @ http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#series-object

You may want to use addPoint or setData, as per your requirements.

I don't recommend doing it the say you are doing, but try calling the redraw method (this.redraw()) after you do your magic, http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#chart-object